# react-native fbsdk is returning email undefined despite of all the permissions granted

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I m trying to get information through the facebook sdk but so far I'm getting only the id and the name of the user. I do have granted the premission but still the email is popping out like name and id. I have almost tried everything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```
      import React, { Component } from 'react'
       import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
         import { LoginButton, AccessToken, LoginManager, GraphRequest, 
           GraphRequestManager } from 'react-native-fbsdk';

              export default class App extends Component {
               constructor() {
              super();
                this._fbAuth = this._fbAuth.bind(this);
                          }
                      _fbAuth = () => {
               var that = this;
             LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 
             'email']).then(function (result) {
                if (result.isCancelled) {
           console.log("Login Cancel");
           alert("Login Cancel")
              //debugger
            }
             else {
               console.log("Login AccessToken");
               alert("Login AccessToken");
              AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                       (data) => {
        //      alert("Get AccessToken");
        //debugger
              let accessToken = data.accessToken;
             alert(accessToken.toString());
               const responseInfoCallback = (error, result) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
            if (error) {
              alert('Errorrrrrrrrr');

            }
            else {
              if (result.email == undefined) {
                alert("Error ,Email address is required");
                // stuck at email. result.name and result.id gives correct results

              }
              else {
                alert(result.email);
              }
            }
          }, 200
          );
        }
        const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
          '/me',
          {
            accessToken: accessToken,
            prameters: {
              fields: {
                string: 'email , name,first_name, middle_name, last_name'
              }
            }
          },
          responseInfoCallback
        );
        new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();

               })
                  }
                  },
           function (error) {
            console.log("some error occured!!", error);
          })

            }

           render() {
         return (
             <View>
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._fbAuth()}>
               <Text>  Press me</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
             }

                   }
```

result.email should not be undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the `accessToken` provided by `fbsdk`.
Just get the `accessToken`, once you receive the `accessToken`, You can make request to facebook graph api's to receive data related to that user using the `accessToken`.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api

Here is the full documentation and It also includes the accessToken. It would help you. 
I also do the same.